# file accessible through https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I need to be able to access the logo of my site via HTTPS. How can I do that?

Comment: please provide more detail, don't make people play a guessing game as to what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the file simply by using the https protocol:

```
https://mysite.com/mylogo.jpg
```

Keep in mind, you will need a valid ssl certificate for your domain.
It's difficult to tell what you're after here with no context and such a short question, so hopefully this helps and you can move on to the next part of your project.

GL!

Comment: I'm unable to access it like that. That is why I'm asking what should I do so I would be able to.

Comment: So you have a site that works over https but you just can't access one file (the logo)? Please expand your question to include details that will help others to answer your question: At the bare minimum: 1. What did you try? 2. What did you get?

Comment: +1 to cancel the downvote, as the answer is technically correct and answers the question **in its current state**. If it doesn't solve the question that is due to the OP asking a bad question and not providing enough detail.

Comment: @slugster: In all fairness the downvote was due to my original rude answer.

Comment: @Mad, true, your first answer was quite brusque and it's good that you elaborated, and your answer is still correct so the upvote stays :)

Comment: @slugster: When I get to the point where I'm even considering answering something that way, no matter how terrible the question is, I know it's time to give it a rest. Interesting that OP just came back and accepted this, with no explanation or adjustment to the question...